# I have a struggle in adding this two queries in one query

Tags: mysql

```
Select s.SID , s.Lastname, s.Firstname, s.MI, g.YearLevel, g.Course,
                count(s.SID) As 'Number Of Passed Subject'
                From student s 
                inner Join grades g on g.StudentID = s.SID
                Where g.Completion = 'Passed' and g.YearLevel = '4th Year'
                group by g.YearLevel, g.Course
                order by g.YearLevel, g.Course;
            
Select s1.SID , s1.Lastname, s1.Firstname, s1.MI, g1.YearLevel, g1.Course,
               SUM(su.LecUnit) As 'Total of Units Passed' 
               From grades g1
               INNER Join student s1 ON s1.SID = g1.StudentID 
               INNER Join subjects su ON su.SubjectCode = g1.SubjectCode 
               WHERE g1.Completion = 'Passed' AND g1.YearLevel = '4th Year'
               GROUP BY g1.Course, g1.YearLevel
               order by g1.Course, g1.YearLevel;
```

Comment: Hi!, Please check [ask]

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: use union to put them follow by each other.

Comment: I want to be the output is I can combine these two queries in the same row ... I tried to use union all clause but it always an error .. 

Error Code: 1250. Table 'g' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Comment: you can't use order by in Union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second query as the starting point, and then add a distinct count of student courses for the number of passed subjects.  The logic here is that the additional join to the `subjects` table might duplicate each intermediate record from the first two joins.  Taking the distinct count removes this possible duplication.

```sql
Select s1.SID, s1.Lastname, s1.Firstname, s1.MI,
       COUNT(DISTINCT g1.Course) As `Number Of Passed Subject`,
       SUM(su.LecUnit) As `Total of Units Passed`
FROM student s1
INNER JOIN grades g1 ON s1.SID = g1.StudentID
INNER JOIN subjects su ON su.SubjectCode = g1.SubjectCode
WHERE g1.Completion = 'Passed' AND g1.YearLevel = '4th Year'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Note that I am also grouping only by `s1.SID`.  Assuming `SID` be the primary key from that table, it covers all columns from the `student` table.  The other table fields you were selecting probably don't belong there.